# Setting inference parameters in the Cyc Java APIs

Tags: opencyc

I have a query that I'm asking from a Java program via the Query API that requires more problem space than the default.  Is the :MAX-PROBLEM-SPACE parameter accessible through the APIs?  If so, how do I set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `com.cyc.baseclient.inference.params.DefaultInferenceParameters` class provides a `put` method that allows you to set the value of any inference parameter that you know the SubL keyword symbol name for. For instance:

```
DefaultInferenceParameters params = new DefaultInferenceParameters(cyc);
params.put(CycObjectFactory.makeCycSymbol(":max-problem-count"), 500000);
```

Comment: Just a quick follow up on this. It looks as if many of the methods that you can use on `DefaultInferenceParameters` objects can also be used on `Query` objects. Originally, I was doing things like `setContinuable(false)` right on the `Query` instance. To use the suggestion above, I had to switch from doing that and do everything on the new `params` variable. Then I used `setInferenceParameters(params)` on the `Query` object. This seems to be working fine, but this was a point of minor confusion.